# Difference between total and execution time in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

When I run any SQL in PostgreSQL manager I'm coming across execution time: 328 ms; total time: 391 ms. I'm wondering what is this two times that is execution time and 
total time.

Comment: execution time is the time which processor takes to finish particular job. this time can be vary as per system to system in case of different configuration. Total time is the time which start from SQL running and finish till get output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what PostgreSQL manager is, but it is most likely combination of those:

```
Planning time: 0.430 ms
Execution time: 150.225 ms
```

Planning is how long it takes for Postgres to decide how to get your data. You send query and server might try to optimize it, that takes time.

Execution is how long it took to actually run that plan.

You can verify it yourself if you send your query like that:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)
SELECT something FROM table WHERE whatever = 5;
```